# How to sync changes of mongoDB database in Redis using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, mean-stack, mern

The problem statement is given below:
First I have created some posts using my backend API then at the time of fetching the posts at first I look up at Redis if there exists the key related to that posts then I returned the data else I send the request to MongoDB and get all those posts and then save it to Redis.
Now again I make request to fetch data then getting data from Redis correctly. But problem is that when now I add another post using POST request from my backend and then again update my redis, it successfully created in mongoDB but when I fecth the posts then I am getting older cached posts instead of all the posts including newer posts.

```
router.get('/posts',(req, res)=>{
  // check if any hashed data is there in redis 
  client.get('posts',(err, posts)=>{
    if(posts){
      // if yes then send it right away
      console.log('serving from redis ');
      return res.json({success: true, posts: JSON.parse(posts)});
    } else {
      //  if no then send the request and updated the redis with the new data 
      console.log('serving from mongoDB');
      Post.find({})
        .sort('-date')
        .populate('user', ['name', 'avatar', 'email'])
        .populate('profile')
        .exec((err, posts)=>{
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.status(404).json({success: false, err});
          } 
          if(posts){
            // now update the redis cache       
            client.set('posts', JSON.stringify(posts));
            res.json({success: true, posts: posts});
          }
        })
      }
    });
});
```

Here is the code for creating posts and update redis: -

```
router.post('/create',passport.authenticate('jwt',{session: false}),(req, res)=>{
  // check if profile for the user exists or not 
  Profile.findOne({user: req.user.id})
    .then((proifle)=>{
      console.log(proifle);
      if(!profile){
        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Please create the profile first'});
      } else {
        // create post 
        const newPost = new Post({
          profile: profile._id,
          user: req.user.id,
          title: req.body.title,
          description: req.body.description,
          requiredFunding: req.body.requiredFunding,
          date: Date.now()
        })
        newPost.save()
          .then((post)=>{
            console.log(post);
            // set post in the redis 
            client.set(JSON.stringify(post._id), JSON.stringify(post));
            res.json({success: true, post});
          })
          .catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
          })
      }
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err);
      res.status(404).json({success: false, err});
    })
});
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the new post is not getting added in the ```posts``` keys of redis. So how can I append the new post in redis ?

Comment: You might note that whilst the callback on methods like `client.set()` are *optional*, it's probably also the only way you can absolutely confirm something was indeed written and that there was not a resulting error. I suggest you use them

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn, I added that is getting added corresponding to the key ```postId``` but I want the posts to append into the ```posts``` key of redis as well. How can I acheive that I mean how can I update the array of posts i.e ``posts``` key of redis  ?

Comment: Okay I think I see what you are asking and where the huge fail in your logic is. You are asking redis to fetch the "cached" posts and then basically skipping over any attempt to update it is as long as a result was returned from the cache. The problem is that after the first write to your redis cache there is **always** something there. Basically you need to add a similar "get all posts" and also write back to the `posts` key within your `/create` route, just as you have for a singular post. Redis has no "append". So you if want a "stringified list" then you redo that list on every added post

Comment: Another approach might be to include a "timestamp" value in the data you serialize. In that way a "cache hit" can then check the timestamp, and where it is older than a set period you can simple branch to the "get from MongoDB" part just as if there was no result, i.e "invalidate". A similar "invalidate" could remove the entire list whenever a new post is added. In that way the "fetch" would again fall back to MongoDB since the key no longer existed. Your choice really.

Comment: Oh, I thought of first approach but I am not sure that the array of posts will be overwritten with a singular post or it will update the posts array with a new post in it?

Comment: The second approach looks great.

Comment: I honestly think you should look at the whole process more closely. The only point of having a separate "cache" is to reduce the load on the main service. However when you consider you need to fetch your "list" on every single addition you would in fact be increasing the load on MongoDB ( and your application ) dramatically. Seems to me that this would worsen performance overall rather than improve it.

Comment: Oh thanks @NeilLunn, Can you please share some resources where I find some more details about optimizing the performance of Node.js web app. I am working on optimization for the first time so getting my hands dirty by practical approach, don't know pros and cons of the process for now.